# Can't compile / install LightGBM for GPU

Tags: r, rstudio, lightgbm

I tried several ways to compile LightGBM under Windows (10) for R.

Everything failed, the most convincing way, installing with Laurae2/lgbdl 
also failes.

when executing :
devtools::install_github("Laurae2/LightGBM", subdir = "R-package")
the following Error stops the installation after a long list of compilation lines:

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'lightgbm' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 kann shared object 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lightgbm/libs/i386/lib_lightgbm.dll' nicht laden:
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this by myself.
Deinstall R for 32 bit. Only 64bit for LightGBM